# Detect attached audio devices iOS

Tags: ios, audio, bluetooth

I'm trying to figure out how to detect which if any audio devices are connected on iphone/ipad/ipod. I know all about the audio route calls and route change callbacks but these don't tell me anything about what's attached. They only report where the audio is currently routing. I need to know, for instance, if headphones and/or bluetooth are still attached while audio is routed through the speakers.  Or, for instance, if a user plugs in the headset while using bluetooth then decides to disconnect bluetooth, I need to know that the bluetooth is disconnected even as audio is still routing through headphones.

Comment: I have a similar issue in my app, my app is playing stream correctly but if I change audio output (unplugged headphone), it stop playing.. did u figureout how to detect when audio output is changed?

Comment: Yes, detecting a route change is do via an AudioSessionPropertyListener callback. The property listener is then registered via the AudioSessionAddPropertyListener function. However that's not what I was trying to do above. In my app I need to detect which devices are connected to correctly display available routing options to the user.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, as of iOS11, it seems there's no API to reliably get the list of the output devices that are currently attached - as soon as the current route changes, you only see 1 device (currently routed) via AVAudioSession's `currentRoute.outputs`, even though multiple devices may still be attached.

However, for the input, and that includes Bluetooth devices with HFP profile, if the proper Audio Session mode is used (`AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat` or `AVAudioSessionModeVideoChat` for example), one can get the list of the available input via AVAudioSession's `availableInputs`, and those inputs are listed there even when that device is not an active route - this is very useful when a user is doing a manual override via `MPVolumeView` from Bluetooth to the speaker, for example, and since HFP is a 2-way IO (has both input and output), you can judge whether output HFP Bluetooth is still available by looking at the inputs.

```
BOOL isBtInputAvailable = NO;
NSArray *inputs = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] availableInputs];
for (AVAudioSessionPortDescription* port in inputs) {
    if ([port.portType isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothHFP]) {
        isBtInputAvailable = YES;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Has there been any updates to this? It frustrates me that I can only know about the connection status of one bluetooth device, and I also must be in `.playAndRecord` or `.record` modes to do so.

Answer (score 1):

In case of iOS 5 you should use:

```
CFStringRef newRoute;
size = sizeof(CFStringRef);
XThrowIfError(AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute, &size, &newRoute), "couldn't get new audio route");
if (newRoute)
{
    CFShow(newRoute);
    if (CFStringCompare(newRoute, CFSTR("HeadsetInOut"), NULL) == kCFCompareEqualTo) // headset plugged in
          {
            colorLevels[0] = .3;                
            colorLevels[5] = .5;
          }
    else if (CFStringCompare(newRoute, CFSTR("SpeakerAndMicrophone"), NULL) == kCFCompareEqualTo)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get from AudioSession properties a list of InputSources and OutputDestinations.
Check out these Session Properties:

```
kAudioSessionProperty_InputSources
kAudioSessionProperty_OutputDestinations
```

And to query the details of each, you can use:

```
kAudioSessionProperty_InputSource
kAudioSessionProperty_OutputDestination
```

Comment: These properties are for USB accessories so they do not apply in my situation. I am looking to detect when a bluetooth or wired headset is attached.

Comment: Oops, my apologies, I see the difference in your question now.