# Can I find out whether the user is driving?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth

I am writing an app for iOS.

I want to know the user's current motion type, for example, walking, driving running.  In particular I am interested in knowing whether they are driving.

I would also like to detect when the device connects to a car Bluetooth, as this may also indicate that they are driving.

Comment: From my anecdotical experience of about 5 years ago, iOS would kill any app on a background, unless you start constantly querying a gps location from the app. Downside of that approach is that frequent use of location services drains the device battery faster. The only viable solution that I can think of – if the user wears a smart watch that talks to an iPhone.

Comment: While your app is active you can use [`CMMotionActivityManager`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmmotionactivitymanager) to get the current motion type.   Note that it won't tell you whether the person is driving or a passenger or even in another vehicle that has similar motion characteristics, such as a train.  You can't get motion activity updates while your app is suspended.  You could combine it with Signification Location updates to get periodic execution in the background.

Comment: @Paulw11 you should make this an answer so the OP can accept it (and we can up-vote it.) It's a nice clear answer to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your app is active you can use [`CMMotionActivityManager`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmmotionactivitymanager) to get the current motion type.

Note that it won't tell you whether the person is driving or a passenger or even in another vehicle that has similar motion characteristics, such as a train. You can't get motion activity updates while your app is suspended.

You could combine it with Signification Location updates to get periodic execution in the background.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355312/detect-attached-audio-devices-ios) has some suggestions on detecting Bluetooth HFP devices by checking the available audio input devices.  Note that you can't check this in the background and you can't get a "notification" that a HFP has connected unless you are actively inputting or outputting audio - You would need to check periodically